# Cannot upload Multiple documents in Doc Lib

Tags: document-library, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing "Upload Multiple Documents" in SharePoint 2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17682/missing-upload-multiple-documents-in-sharepoint-2007)

I am unable to upload Multiple documents in Doc Lib from some PCs.
Usually it works in Windows XP/Office 2003/IE 8.0.
But does not work on Windows 7/Office 2007/IE 8.0
Can someone please give out solution to this issue.
Its frustrating to upload one doc at a time :(
Thanks
-saumil